# What does the log information mean in android log file?

Tags: android, logging

The log information was printed at logcat.txt file, I wonder what does they mean and where are the codes which is responsible for printing it? Is it that /system/bin/surfaceflinger crash?

--------- beginning of crash

12-28 14:24:12.919  5821  5821 I AEE/AED :

12-28 14:24:12.919  5821  5821 I AEE/AED :

12-28 14:24:12.919  5821  5821 I AEE/AED : ----- pid 293 at 2016-12-28 14:24:12 -----

12-28 14:24:12.919  5821  5821 I AEE/AED : Cmd line: /system/bin/surfaceflinger

12-28 14:24:12.919  5821  5821 I AEE/AED : ABI: 'arm64'

Comment: codes are definitely in Android system source.

Answer (score 0):

Logcats follow this format `date time PID-TID/package priority/tag: message`

where `PID` is process identifier and 
       `TID` is thread identifier

You can log a message by adding `Log.{priority}(tag, message)` where priority is one of `{v,d,i,w,e,a}` inside your application

For more information on them and how to use logcat refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html)

Comment: I know what does the format mean. But don't understand that "Cmd line: /system/bin/surfaceflinger" means.

Comment: Since you *know* what the format means you should be knowing that it is an info log and not an error log.. So it is just an info log printed by surface flinger when its executed..